# Yii2: How to add id's or classes on just a popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have a problem here. In my GridView I have a column `status` and when I click on it, it shows the popover, which is the comment from the database.

What I need to do is to add a specific class for a whole popover and the specific id on popover-title...

Is it possible to do so?

Here's what I have:

```
  return Html::a('<span class="status-content">'.Yii::t('app', 'STATUS'),'#', [
     'title' => Module::t('app', 'Comment'),
      'data-toggle' => 'popover',
      'data-content' => $model->comment,
      'data-placement' => 'top',
 ]);
```

For the title id I was trying to use `Html::tag`, but this didn't helped..

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more about bootstrap than yii2, you should read this :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers

You can use `template` option, e.g. :

```
return Html::a('<span class="status-content">'.Yii::t('app', 'STATUS'),'#', [
    'title' => Module::t('app', 'Comment'),
    'data-toggle' => 'popover',
    'data-content' => $model->comment,
    'data-placement' => 'top',
    'data-template' => '<div class="popover my-class" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title" id="my-id"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>',
]);
```